# SharePoint - Attach event receivers for a specific folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development

We have a SharePoint Document library which consist Folders. I want to attach Event Receiver for an specific Folder in library.

Means Event Receiver will only fire when any change happens in specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

straight forward.. just create an event on ItemUpdate and first line will be to check if the item title is that of the folder then give your action code else no action. So event receiver will fire each time the item in the library modifies but will do the action only if the title matches that of your folder.

Comment: Agree with you, but looking for an optimize way. Event receiver only fire when added/modification in specific Folder in Library.

Comment: That is not possible.. the event receiver provided by SharePoint is ItemUpdate and Item Added. There is nothing to have on a folder level. You can only have a check each time event receiver fire.